# Adding rows to a pandas dataframe with respect to existing entities within the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, filled with values that look like this.  I only have rows for months where entities generated revenue, but entities may have had lifetimes longer than what is depicted by the revenue they're showing.

| entity | revenue_generated | first_purchase | months_since_first_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 2022-01 | 0 |
| A | 60 | 2022-01 | 2 |
| A | 80 | 2022-01 | 3 |
| A | 15 | 2022-01 | 5 |
| B | 30 | 2022-03 | 0 |
| B | 10 | 2022-03 | 1 |
| B | 12 | 2022-03 | 2 |
| G | 25 | 2022-01 | 0 |
| G | 19 | 2022-01 | 1 |
| G | 90 | 2022-01 | 2 |

For a quick explanation of a lifetime in this context,  Entity A first purchased during January 2022.  5 months since their first purchase, where they generated $15 is the maximum of the lifetime.  In other words, since I am writing this in June 2022, we have no visibility of their purchase history in July 2022.  So their maximum potential lifetime as a customer is 5 months, (representing the 6 observable months of Jan, Feb, March, April, May and June and starting the count from 0)

For simplicity's sake, let's say B first purchased in March 2022, so their maximum is 3.  So A's maximum potential lifetime is represented in the dataset, but B's and G's are not.

G also made their first purchased in January 2022.  So their maximum `months_since_first_purchase` value is also 5, but they did not generate any revenue during that month so they are not represented.

I want to change the dataset so it includes all of the months_since_first_purchase for each entity and includes their revenue in that month as 0.  So, my goal dataset (with additions emphasised) is:

| entity | revenue_generated | first_purchase | months_since_first_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 2022-01 | 0 |
| **A** | **0** | **2022-01** | **1** |
| A | 60 | 2022-01 | 2 |
| A | 80 | 2022-01 | 3 |
| **A** | **0** | **2022-01** | **4** |
| A | 15 | 2022-01 | 5 |
| B | 30 | 2022-03 | 0 |
| B | 10 | 2022-03 | 1 |
| B | 12 | 2022-03 | 2 |
| **B** | **0** | **2022-03** | **3** |
| G | 25 | 2022-01 | 0 |
| G | 19 | 2022-01 | 1 |
| G | 90 | 2022-01 | 2 |
| **G** | **0** | **2022-01** | **3** |
| **G** | **0** | **2022-01** | **4** |
| **G** | **0** | **2022-01** | **5** |

I currently have this implemented in a for loop where I iterate over a set of the entities, and build a new dataframe for each of them and concatenate it to a new main dataframe but this is quite slow.  Is there a more pythonic way of approaching this problem with Pandas that doesn't involve iterating and rebuilding a new dataframe?

Comment: Isn't B/March's maximum 3?

Comment: The way it was originally written, A and G's first maximum months should've actually been 4.  But I have adjusted the question so that B's maximum is 3 and fixed the off-by-one error in the explanation.  Nice catch!

Comment: Mostly caught it because otherwise my answer's output wouldn't match :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the `pd.date_range` method to generate the required missing months and then merging back with the original dataset

- **First**, generate the missing dates till `now_date` using the `pd.date_range` function

```py
now_date = '2022-05-01'
g = df.groupby(['entity']).agg({'first_purchase': 'min'})
g.loc[:, 'all_months'] = g.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['first_purchase'], end=pd.to_datetime(now_date), freq='MS'), axis=1)
```

- **Next**, we expand these dates into separate rows and compute the `months_since_first_purchase`

```py
g_stacked = g.explode('all_months')
g_stacked.loc[:, 'months_since_first_purchase'] = (g_stacked['all_months'].dt.year - pd.to_datetime(g_stacked['first_purchase']).dt.year)*12 + (g_stacked['all_months'].dt.month - pd.to_datetime(g_stacked['first_purchase']).dt.month)
```

- **And finally**, merge back with the original dataset and fill the blanks

```py
g_stacked = g_stacked.set_index('months_since_first_purchase', append=True)
g_stacked = g_stacked.drop('first_purchase', axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['entity', 'months_since_first_purchase'])
df_new = g_stacked.join(df, how='left')
df_new.loc[:, 'revenue_generated'] = df_new['revenue_generated'].fillna(0)
df_new.loc[:, 'first_purchase'] = df_new['first_purchase'].fillna(method='ffill')
df_new = df_new.reset_index()
df_new
```

This is what the output looks like

```
   entity  months_since_first_purchase all_months  revenue_generated first_purchase
0       A                            0 2022-01-01               20.0        2022-01
1       A                            1 2022-02-01                0.0        2022-01
2       A                            2 2022-03-01               60.0        2022-01
3       A                            3 2022-04-01               80.0        2022-01
4       A                            4 2022-05-01                0.0        2022-01
5       B                            0 2022-03-01               30.0        2022-03
6       B                            1 2022-04-01               10.0        2022-03
7       B                            2 2022-05-01               12.0        2022-03
8       G                            0 2022-01-01               25.0        2022-01
9       G                            1 2022-02-01               19.0        2022-01
10      G                            2 2022-03-01               90.0        2022-01
11      G                            3 2022-04-01                0.0        2022-01
12      G                            4 2022-05-01                0.0        2022-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible without looping, but I think creating a new dataframe simplifies it a bit.

With a simpler example...

```
  entity  revenue_generated  first_purchase  months_since_first_purchase
0      A                 15          202201                            0
1      A                 20          202201                            1
2      A                 40          202201                            4
3      B                 80          202203                            0
4      B                 60          202203                            2
```

```
# reference value to determine number of repeats for each entity
ref_val = 202206
df['repeats'] = ref_val - df['first_purchase']

# create second dataframe with shell of just entity and months since first purchase
df2 = df[['entity','repeats']].drop_duplicates().set_index('entity')
df2 = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2['repeats'])]
df2['months_since_first_purchase'] = df2.groupby(level=-1).cumcount()

# merge back and fill in the rest of the data
df2 = df2.reset_index().drop(columns=['repeats']).merge(df.drop(columns=['repeats']), 'left', on=['entity','months_since_first_purchase'])
df2['revenue_generated'] = df2['revenue_generated'].fillna(0)
df2['first_purchase'] = df2.groupby('entity')['first_purchase'].ffill()
```

```
  entity  months_since_first_purchase  revenue_generated  first_purchase
0      A                            0               15.0        202201.0
1      A                            1               20.0        202201.0
2      A                            2                0.0        202201.0
3      A                            3                0.0        202201.0
4      A                            4               40.0        202201.0
5      B                            0               80.0        202203.0
6      B                            1                0.0        202203.0
7      B                            2               60.0        202203.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to dynamically resolve all of your data

```
#Finds the Maximum Month since last purchase
df['Count'] = df.groupby('entity')['months_since_first_purchase'].transform(max)

#Creates a new df which has only the max entity and the max month since first purchase
df_counter = df[['entity', 'Count']].drop_duplicates()

#Creates a list the length of the months since first purchase
df_counter['Count'] = df_counter['Count'].apply(lambda x : ([1] + [1] * x))

#explodes the count column to get all possible numbers
df_counter = df_counter.explode('Count')

#Changes to a count instead of just the number 1
df_counter['Count'] = df_counter.groupby('entity')['Count'].cumcount()

#Joins the df_counter df to the main df leftly so all missing values are just np.nan
df_final = pd.merge(df_counter, df, how = 'left', left_on = ['entity', 'Count'], right_on = ['entity', 'months_since_first_purchase'])

#Limits the columns selected
df_final = df_final[['entity', 'Count_x', 'revenue_generated', 'first_purchase']]

#Changes the column names
df_final.columns = ['entity', 'months_since_first_purchase', 'revenue_generated', 'first_purchase']

#Changes all np.nan's to Nones
df_final['revenue_generated'] = df_final['revenue_generated'].replace({np.nan : None})

#Find where 'revenue_generated' == None and change it to 0 else leave it alone
df_final['revenue_generated'] = np.where(df_final['revenue_generated'].values == None, 0, df_final['revenue_generated'])

#Forward fills all the data in the first purchase column to replace the np.nan's
df_final['first_purchase'] = df_final['first_purchase'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# First, make a datetime index from the information we have.
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.first_purchase.str.split('-').str[0] + ' ' +
               (df.first_purchase.str.split('-').str[1].astype(int) 
                + df.months_since_first_purchase).astype(str))

# Groupby entity, pick the desired columns and reindex each group
df = df.groupby('entity')[['revenue_generated', 'first_purchase', 'months_since_first_purchase']].apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range('2022-01', periods=6, freq='MS')))

# Reset the index back to what we want
df = df.reset_index(-2).reset_index(drop=True)

# Do the fills
df.revenue_generated = df.revenue_generated.fillna(0)
df.first_purchase = df.groupby('entity')['first_purchase'].ffill()

# Drop the excess data
df = df.dropna(subset='first_purchase')

# Fix the months_since column
df.loc[:,'months_since_first_purchase'] = df.groupby('entity').cumcount().tolist()
```

Output:

| entity | revenue_generated | first_purchase | months_since_first_purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 2022-01 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 2022-01 | 1 |
| A | 60 | 2022-01 | 2 |
| A | 80 | 2022-01 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 2022-01 | 4 |
| A | 15 | 2022-01 | 5 |
| B | 30 | 2022-03 | 0 |
| B | 10 | 2022-03 | 1 |
| B | 12 | 2022-03 | 2 |
| B | 0 | 2022-03 | 3 |
| G | 25 | 2022-01 | 0 |
| G | 19 | 2022-01 | 1 |
| G | 90 | 2022-01 | 2 |
| G | 0 | 2022-01 | 3 |
| G | 0 | 2022-01 | 4 |
| G | 0 | 2022-01 | 5 |